# My submenu on css is not working property and is hiding a few buttons

Tags: html, css

With this code I have problems because just I have this and I want that those submenus comes over the all menu and then we can select it

[image]

If we can see Promedio 2 and promedio 3 are behind of or menu

```css
    @charset "utf-8";
   

    #menu2,
    #menu2 ul,
    #menu2 li,
    #menu2 a {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     border: none;
     outline: none;
    }

    /* menu2 */
    #menu2 { 
      width:850px;
      height:33px;
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
      font-size:13px;
      vertical-align:top;
      float:left;
      border-top-right-radius:10px;
     
     /*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7b0100 0%,#7b0100 100%);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7b0100 0%,#7b0100 100%);
     background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7b0100 0%,#7b0100 100%);
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7b0100 0%,#7b0100 100%);
     background: linear-gradient(top, #7b0100 0%,#7b0100 100%);
     */
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
    }
    #menu2 li:hover{
     background:#000066;
     color:#FF0;
     
    }

    #li_menu{
      width:80px;
      text-align:center;
      padding:0px;
      margin:0px;
     }
     
    #li_submenu{
      text-align:left;
     }
     
    #menu2 li {
     position: relative;
     list-style: none;
     float: left;
     display: block;
     height: 34px;
    }

    /* Links */

    #menu2 li a {
     display: block;
     padding: 0 14px;
     margin: 6px 0;
     line-height: 28px;
     text-decoration: none;
     
     border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
     border-right: 1px solid #9000;

     font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 13px;

     color: #FFFFFF;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);

     -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
     transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    }

    #menu2 li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
    #menu2 li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }

    #menu2 li:hover > a { color: #FFFF00; }

    /* Sub menu2 */

    #menu2 ul {
     position: absolute;
     top: 40px;
     left: 0;

     opacity: 0;
     
     background: #0000FF;

     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
     border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

     -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
     -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
     -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
     -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
     transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    }


    #menu2 li:hover > ul {
      opacity: 1; 
    }

    #menu2 ul li {
     height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 0;

     -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
     -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
     -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
     -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
     transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    }

    #menu2 li:hover > ul li {
     height: 34px;
     overflow: visible;
     padding: 0;
    }

    #menu2 ul li a {
     width: 120px;
     padding: 4px 0 4px 30px;
     margin: 0;

     border: none;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #4F0002;
    }



    +++++++++++++++

    #menu, #menu ul {

     list-style:none;
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
     
    }

    #menu li {
     float:center;
     position:relative;
     line-height: 4.5em;
     width: 10em;
    }
    #menu li ul {
     position:absolute;
     margin-top:-1em;
     margin-left:.5em;
     display:none;
    }
    #menu ul li ul {
     margin-top:-3em;
     margin-left:7em;
    }
    #menu a {
     display:block;
     border-right:0px solid #fff;
     color:#FFFFFF;
     text-decoration:none;
     padding:0 10px;
    }
    #menu a:hover {
     background-color:#0000FF;
     color:#fff;
    }
    #menu ul {
     border-top:1px solid #fff;
    }
    #menu ul a {
     border-right:none;
     border-right:1px solid #fff;
     border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
     border-left:1px solid #fff;
     background:#0000FF;
    }
    /* SHOW SUBMENU 1 */
    #menu li:hover ul, #menu li.over ul {
     display:block;
     position: absolute;
    }
    #menu li:hover ul ul, #menu li.over ul ul {
     display:none;
    }
    /* SHOW SUBMENU 2 */
    #menu ul li:hover ul, #menu ul li.over ul {
     display:block;
    }

    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

```html
      <li id="menu"><a href="">Examenes</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li id="menu"><a href="#" >Calendario</a>
          <ul id="menu li.over ul">
            <li id="menu"><a href="#" >Calendario 1</a>
             <ul id="menu li.over ul">
              <li id="menu2_ul_li_a"><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry>Matematicas</a>
               <ul id="menu2_ul_li_a">
                 <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">3</a></li>
               </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Fisica</a>
               <ul>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">3</a></li>
               </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">E. Fisica</a>
               <ul>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">3</a></li>
               </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Artisticas</a>
               <ul>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">3</a></li>
               </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Historia</a>
               <ul>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">3</a></li>
               </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Taller</a>
               <ul>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">3</a></li>
               </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Biologia</a>
               <ul>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" >1</a></li>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" >2</a></li>
                <li><a href="examen2.php" >3</a></li>
               </ul>
              </li>
             </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="menu"><a href="#" >Promedio 1ero</a>
           <ul id="menu li.over ul">
            <li id="menu"><a href="examen2.php" tag=Espanol class="stocks">Espa&ntilde;ol</a></li>
            <li id="menu"><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Matematicas</a></li>
            <li id="menu li"><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Fisica</a></li>
            <li id="menu li"><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">E. Fisica</a></li>
            <li id="menu2 li:hover > ul "><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Artisticas</a></li>
            <li id="menu li"><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Historia</a></li>
            <li id="menu li"><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Taller</a></li>
            <li id="menu li"><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Biologia</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="menu"><a href="#" class="sales">Segundo</a>
           <ul id="menu li.over ul">
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Espa&ntilde;ol</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Matematicas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Fisica</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">E. Fisica</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Artisticas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Historia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Taller</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Biologia</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
                            <li id="menu"><a href="#" class="sales">Tercero</a>
          <ul id="menu li.over ul">
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Espa&ntilde;ol</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Matematicas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Fisica</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">E. Fisica</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Artisticas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Historia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Taller</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Biologia</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

```
#menu2,
#menu2 ul,
#menu2 li,
#menu2 a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

/* menu2 */
#menu2 {    
        width:850px;
        height:33px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        font-size:13px;
        vertical-align:top;
        float:left;
        border-top-right-radius:10px;

    /*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7b0100 0%,#7b0100 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7b0100 0%,#7b0100 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7b0100 0%,#7b0100 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7b0100 0%,#7b0100 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #7b0100 0%,#7b0100 100%);
    */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#menu2 li:hover{
    background:#000066;
    color:#FF0;

}

#li_menu{
        width:80px;
        text-align:center;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }

#li_submenu{
        text-align:left;
    }

#menu2 li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 34px;
}

/* Links */

#menu2 li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 14px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;

    border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #9000;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;

    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);

    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu2 li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
#menu2 li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }

#menu2 li:hover > a { color: #FFFF00; }

/* Sub menu2 */

#menu2 ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;

    opacity: 0;

    background: #0000FF;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}


#menu2 li:hover > ul {
     opacity: 1; 
}

#menu2 ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}

#menu2 li:hover > ul li {
    height: 34px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu2 ul li a {
    width: 120px;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 30px;
    margin: 0;

    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4F0002;
}



+++++++++++++++

#menu, #menu ul {

    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}

#menu li {
    float:center;
    position:relative;
    line-height: 4.5em;
    width: 10em;
}
#menu li ul {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-1em;
    margin-left:.5em;
    display:none;
}
#menu ul li ul {
    margin-top:-3em;
    margin-left:7em;
}
#menu a {
    display:block;
    border-right:0px solid #fff;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0 10px;
}
#menu a:hover {
    background-color:#0000FF;
    color:#fff;
}
#menu ul {
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
}
#menu ul a {
    border-right:none;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    background:#0000FF;
}
/* SHOW SUBMENU 1 */
#menu li:hover ul, #menu li.over ul {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
}
#menu li:hover ul ul, #menu li.over ul ul {
    display:none;
}
/* SHOW SUBMENU 2 */
#menu ul li:hover ul, #menu ul li.over ul {
    display:block;
}
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: in your code snippet menu vertical and you image show horizontal so which one is correct?

Comment: The horizontal is the correct, I have other options in the same css vertical and horizontal... I want fix just the horizontal...

Comment: If you want to correct horizontal menu so provide your horizontal menu css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some important notes:

- You really need to clean it up.
- Do not repeat id's. They are meant to
  be unique.
- `float: center` does not exist
- classes with a dot (li.over) are not well supported. Use - or _ (li-over,li_over)
- there is more than one way to do this. [Here is one](https://jsfiddle.net/8ahm5gmh/). On this solution, you add the class `has-submenu` to the list element with a submenu

Comment: Really, I'm sorry, I am novie, I am learning how it works... but I will take it with good eyes... ;)

Comment: Very good... I done thnsk... it is working now... thank you...